# add signature to several articles via SQL / PhpMyAdmin

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

I have more than a hundred of different articles, and I would like to add at the end of each one (without deleting the existing content) a same and unique comment :

```
<br/>signature blabla<br/>
```

I want to use PhpMyAdmin and SQl to do that inside the table xxx_content in the column introtext (at the end of the content) 
All the articles are from different categories (catid=778,779,780)

The code should be something like :

```
INSERT INTO introtext FROM xxx_content(WHERE catid=778,779,780) THIS (<br/>signature blabla<br/>) at the end of the content
```

This `<br/>signature blabla<br/>` will then be editable from the article editor.

Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understood it like you actually want to update existing content:

```
UPDATE yourTable 
SET yourTextColumn = CONCAT(yourTextColumn, '<br/>signature blabla<br/>') 
WHERE catid IN (778, 779, 780);
```

Comment: @Giom How about some feedback?

Comment: Yes! That works perfectly! Thanks so much, you are the man, tombom! With all my gratefulness, giom